# How can I make my site’s visitors access my web pages without adding the page extension

Tags: php, apache

I am a beginner and I have just hosted my first ever website; the problem I am faced with now is how to make my site visitors access pages on my site even without adding the page extension.

Example: www.example.com/services   Instead of www.example.com/services.php

Comment: See this answered already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit .htaccess file   and add the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and it will be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use [url rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) to append the extension when one is not specified. OR you could build a routing system to link specific uri to a specific resource ([quick example here](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241)). The latter introduces a lot of complexity but gives much more control. For example, here is basic pseudo code based on a custom routing system I built:

```
$routes->addStaticRoute(
    /* Pattern */ '/home/myPage',
    /* Params  */ null,
    /* File    */ 'path/to/myPage.php'
);
```

All requests automatically go to index.php where my router translates the url request into an actual routes to a resource. With the above static route, if a user requests `http://mySite/home/myPage`, the router will respond with the static file at path `wwwroot/path/to/myPage.php`.

Another example of a static route:

```
$routes->addStaticRoute(
    /* Pattern */ '/home/{fileName}.{extension}',
    /* Params  */ ['fileName' => 'index', 'extension' => 'php'],
    /* File    */ 'path/to/{fileName}.{extension}'
);
```

If a user requests `http://mySite/home` the router will respond with the default `wwwroot/path/to/index.php`. Further, if they request `http://mySite/home/page5`, router will respond with (if exists) `wwwroot/path/to/page5.php`.

Routing is somewhat of an advanced concept and these are some oversimplified examples but I hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

But if you want to use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])` to allow:

```
http://my.domain/script/a/b
# instead of 
http://my.domain/script.php/a/b
```

... you need something like:

```
# specifix scripts:
RewriteRule ^(script1|script2)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 [L]
# or more general, but with issues for sub-directotries
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.*) $1.php/$2 [L]

# final rules:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```